# JavaScript drop-down menu issues

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, menu

My menu is sliding down into the page as I want but it does not go up to a "0px" i marginTop when I click the image again. The image has a `onclick="meny()"` event.

```
var menu; 
  var x = 0;
  function meny() {

    menu = document.getElementById('menu-slider');

    if(x = 1) {
    menu.style.marginTop = "0px";
    x = 0;
  } else if(x = 0) {
     menu.style.marginTop = "-300px";
      x = 1;

  }

  };
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a better illustration. You can include a live demonstration by pressing Ctrl-M to make a Stack Snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to get rid of the quotes here: `x='0'` and try `x=1` instead of `x=x+1` same goes for the else if

Answer (score 0):

*It should be*

```
if(x == 1) {
    ...
} else if (x == 0) {
    ...
}
```

*rather than*

```
if (x = 1) {
    ...
} else if (x = 0) {
    ...
}
```